# Download a file async?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I cant wrap my head around it, how can I download a image... lets say

```
https://www.google.com/logos/classicplus.png
```

I'm doing this on Windows Phone so I need to do this async and Im having some problems on how to resolv this.

Comment: -1. Please show what have you tried and what you have problem with. At least search terms you've used.

Comment: I agree with @AlexeiLevenkov, you need to show us your code and what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have shown what you have tried and what was the problem you are facing, anyway here is a sample code to achieve this

First create an Image tag in the XAML `<Image x:Name="img" />` and then set its source from the code behind

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(client_OpenReadCompleted);
client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("https://www.google.com/logos/classicplus.png", UriKind.Absolute));
```

and the OpenReadCompleted event handler is

```
void client_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    BitmapImage bmi = new BitmapImage();
    bmi.SetSource(e.Result);
    img.Source = bmi;
}
```

Comment: is it possible to get the file name or the url in client_OpenReadCompleted ?